# KendoUI ComboBox Change Event Runs Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have an MVC Control for a KendoUI ComboBox that does NOT setup the Change Event ahead of time.  Upon rendering, a page controller sets-up & shims-in its' own Change Event.

Oddly, this event gets called TWICE:

- When I change the Selected Item
- When I click away from the control

[image]

**Q:** What am I doing wrong?
**Q:** Is this HOW we should over-write the change event on an existing Kendo ComboBox?

**MVC CONTROL:**
As you can see, I am NOT defining any client-side events here...

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
  .Name("ddlTechnician")
  .Filter("contains")
  .Placeholder("Select Technician...")
  .DataTextField("Text")
  .DataValueField("Value")
  .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
      new SelectListItem() { Text = "Frank", Value = "1" },
      new SelectListItem() { Text = "Suzie", Value = "2" },
      new SelectListItem() { Text = "Ralph", Value = "3" }
  })
  .Suggest(true)
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px;" }))
```

**PAGE CONTROLLER:**
And, I am only defining the event ONCE here.  I have also confirmed the event isn't already firing BEFORE setting it in the Page Controller

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var PageController = (function ($) {

        function PageController(options) {
            var that = this,
                empty = {},
                dictionary = {
                    elements: {
                        form: null
                    },
                    instances: {
                        ddlTechnician: null
                    },
                    selectors: {
                        form: 'form',
                        ddlTechnician: '#ddlTechnician'
                    }
                };

            var initialize = function (options) {
                that.settings = $.extend(empty, $.isPlainObject(options) ? options : empty);

                dictionary.elements.form = $(dictionary.selectors.form);

                // Objects
                dictionary.instances.ddlTechnician = $(dictionary.selectors.ddlTechnician, dictionary.elements.form).data('kendoComboBox');

                // Events
                dictionary.instances.ddlTechnician.setOptions({ change: that.on.change.kendoComboBox });
            };

            this.settings = null;
            this.on = {
                change: {
                    kendoComboBox: function (e) {

                        // This is getting called MULTIPLE TIMES
                        console.log('kendoComboBox RAN');
                    }
                }
                }
            };

            initialize(options);
        }

        return PageController;
    })(jQuery);

    var pageController = new PageController({});
});
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I'm sorry man, but you have GOT to be kidding!  Are we on Jeopardy?  Do we truly HAVE to "answer in the form of a question"?  Can people simply not see the SIMPLE inference here?

The event is running TWICE....and shouldn't.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound sarcastic or anything. It just helps to have a clearly defined question sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem on a Kendo JQuery Combobox when I set the event handler through setOptions, which is not the recommended way after the widget has been rendered. Instead you should use the "bind" method as shown in the [documentation's example for change events](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#events-change).

Try changing the line of code where you set your event handler to this:

```
dictionary.instances.ddlTechnician.bind("change", that.on.change.kendoComboBox);
```

Here's a dojo that shows the difference: http://dojo.telerik.com/iyEQe

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, man :-)  Oddly...I couldnt find that in the Kendo forums...although that could simply be my fault